# Implementing Comparable with a generic doubly linked list

Tags: java, list, generics

I'm writing a doubly linked list that as objects extended from my class "Furniture" are added, sorts them using a compareTo method.

My list and node codes:

```
class Node<E extends Comparable<E>> { ....... }


class DList<E extends Comparable<E>>
{

[..]

    public void add(E c)
    {
        Node<E> finger = head;
        while (finger != null && ((finger.value().compareTo(c)) > 0))
            finger = finger.Next();

    }
}
```

My compareTo method(s) are located in subclasses of my Furniture class, for example:

```
class Chair extends Furniture
{


[.....]

    public int compareTo(Chair c)
    {
    if(this.getStyle().equals(c.getStyle()))
        return this.getColor().compareToIgnoreCase(c.getColor());
    return this.getStyle().compareToIgnoreCase(c.getStyle());
    }


}
```

I then try to make my list by

```
    DList<Furniture> DD = new DList<Furniture>();
```

and I receive the error: Type argument furniture is not within type variable E

Comment: p.s. for best results use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that `Furniture` implements `Comparable<Furniture>`

Comment: And `Chair` will need to implement `int compareTo(Furniture f)` to match.

Comment: No, if Furniture implements Comparable<Furniture> then the class already has a compareTo method and the Chair class will inherit this compareTo method.

Comment: Actually `Chair` will need to implement `Comparable<Chair>`, but only if he needs to instantiate a `DList<Chair>`

Comment: Yes, but that's not the case here, as the op wants to create a DList of Furniture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `Forniture` class does not implement `Comparable<Forniture>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your Furniture class should be abstract and should extend Comparable, your Chair class should implement your Furniture class.

An alternative is to make your Furniture class implement Comparable.

Answer (score 0):

`<E extends Comparable<E>>` means `E` must be extending `Comparable<E>`, so make sure that Furniture extends Comparable.